# pgadmin "server doesn't listen" while creating server on windows7

Tags: postgresql, windows-7, pgadmin

I would like to create a server on pgAdmin III v1.18.1, parameters:
host: localhost
port: 5432
I added postgresql.conf file to base directory of pgadmin application, i tried both "listen_addresses='*'" and "tcpip_socket=true", but i wasn't able to create server. After i creating the .conf file i started pgadmin and selected file->open postgresql.conf, i opened my file and checked if the parameter is fine (example with parameter 'tcpip_socket': [http://screenshot.cz/HQWND/](http://screenshot.cz/)) ->as you can see i cant select all menu buttons, so i can just close the file, so i closed the file and restarted the app, but the problem keeps. Any solutions? thx.

Comment: Did you start your local Postgres server? "*create server*" does not really "create a server" in pgAdmin. It merely defines a _connection_ to a running Postgres server.

Comment: can you help me how to start the local server?

Comment: It's all in the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime.html

Comment: "$ postgres -D /usr/local/pgsql/data >logfile 2>&1 &"hmm i don't get it, where can i find "psql/data" folder?? i just installed pgadmin, not the postgresql, but i read the database is included in pgadmin

Comment: pgAdmin is ***only*** a client tool. It does not include the database server. It's the other way round: if you install the Postgres server you usually also get the pgAdmin client.

Comment: thanks man, my oversight, i forgot i should have a server :)